# Not able to get emoji in React SSR

Tags: reactjs, emoji

I am using this [Emoji](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-picker-react) in my project. I am calling it under the class component but getting the error

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at getPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
```

**My react is in SSR**

On my code this is the implememtation:

```
import Picker from 'emoji-picker-react';

class Post extends React.Component{
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      chosenEmoji: null,
      setChosenEmoji: null,
    }
 }

 onEmojiClick = (event, emojiObject) => {
    this.setState({ chosenEmoji: emojiObject });
 }

 render(){
  return (
    <div>
      <Picker onEmojiClick={this.onEmojiClick} />
    </div>
  )
 }
}
```

**I have debugged by changing the state key to '' or [] but everytime got the different different error**

When I am changing state key to empty

```
this.state={
  chosenEmoji: '',
  setChosenEmoji: '',
}
```

I got this message:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> at ReactDOMServerRenderer.render

Can anyone guide me how to use emoji on the SSR